# Class 'Analytics' not found

Tags: google-analytics, laravel-8

I just downloaded this package on my localhost. Spatie/laravel-analytics its a Google Analytics Package i have followed the documenation of package and it works offline.

---

Offline configuration
Laravel 8.1.2 Spatie/Analytics 3.11.0 PHP 7.3.27 (Windows)

---

Online configuration
Laravel 8.1.2 Spatie/Analytics 3.11.0 PHP 7.4 (Linux) - no access to composer

---

It doesn't work, I get the following error:

**Class 'Analytics' not found
A class import is missing
You have a missing class import. Try importing this class: Google\Service\Analytics.**

*My controller*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Analytics;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;

class Analyticsdash extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        $analyticsConfig = config('analytics');

        $startDate = Carbon::now()->subYear();
        $endDate = Carbon::now();
        $period = Period::create($startDate, $endDate);

        $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
            $period,
            'ga:sessions',
            [
                'metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews',
                'dimensions' => 'ga:yearMonth',
            ]
        );
        $sessions = '';
        $pageviews = '';
        foreach ($analyticsData as $data) {
            if ($sessions) {
                $sessions .= ', ';
                $pageviews .= ', ';
            }
            $sessions .= $data[1];
            $pageviews .= $data[2];
        }
        dd($analyticsData);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating :

```
$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(...)
```

but as the error says, you don't import any class called "Analytics" (that it can find, at least) - so Spatie Analytics probably doesn't provide a facade and will have to be imported with the full class name.

It's suggesting what it thinks is the most appropriate class (Google\Service\Analytics) but if it's the Spatie one you want to import then you need to import it as follows (looking at their Github repo) :

```
use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics;
```

Comment: They explicite, on github, say to import as follows:
use Analytics;
And it works for me offline but online I get the error...